# Using StaticResource to set ListView's Height property throws exception

Tags: wpf, xaml

I define "DisplayHeight" in my App.xaml file here:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="DisplayHeight">534</sys:Int32> 
</Application.Resources>
```

I try to set my ListView Height here:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="myListView" Height="{StaticResource DisplayHeight}"/>
</Grid>
```

This results in the following exception:

```
{"'534' is not a valid value for property 'Height'."}
```

I don't understand why this wouldn't work. I can manually set the height to 534 and it works. Also, I read that a controls "Height" is an "Int32" so it shouldn't be a type problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx) is a `double`, so you need to declare it as such if you want to use `StaticResource` directly.

Alternatively you could wrap it in a Binding which uses type converters:

```xml
Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource DisplayHeight}}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at control height and saw that was an Int32. But, ListView's height derives from FrameworkElement which is a double (like you said).